# boost.python caching wrapped class members

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I have a trivial classes dependency:

```
class A {
    ... // constructor is omitted 
public:
    const std::string str1;
};
class B {
public:
    std::shared_ptr<A> a;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_IMPORT(wrapped) {

    class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>>("APy")
    .def_readonly("str1", &A::str1);

    class_<B>("BPy")
    .def_readwrite("a", &B::a);
}
```

In Python

```
import wrapped as wr
b = wr.BPy()
s1 = b.a.str1 // APy wrapper created
s2 = b.a.str1 // new APy wrapper created even though object is the same
```

Is there some way to create this APy wrapper once for an object?
Especially, because inner object A is immutable(in this particular case).
Otherwise, there is considerable overhead of creating lots of such temporary objects.

Comment: Short answer seems to be: [it just doesn't work](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986581/using-boost-python-stdshared-ptr).

Answer (score 1):

The `APy` wrappers are temporaries because `s1, s2` are strings. Once `s1` is created, Python doesn't care if the setup that created it could also be used to create `s2`. Most likely `b.a` gets discarded because it isn't stored. 
Does the same thing happen when you do something like

```
a1 = b.a
s1 = a1.str1
s2 = a1.str1
```

?

**Update:**

We're trying to find out what b.a actually is in Python.

Your invocation is

```
BOOST_PYTHON_IMPORT(wrapped) {

    class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>>("APy")
    .def_readonly("str1", &A::str1);

    class_<B>("BPy")
    .def_readwrite("a", &B::a);
}
```

The definition of `def_readwrite` in `boost/python/class.hpp` is

```
template <class D>
self& def_readwrite(char const* name, D const& d, char const* doc=0)
{
    return this->def_readwrite_impl(name, d, doc BOOST_PYTHON_DATA_MEMBER_HELPER(D));
}
// translates to
class_<B>& def_readwrite(char const* name, A &d,
  char const* doc=0, detail::is_data_member_pointer<B>()){...}
```

where the best matching implementation of `def_readwrite_impl` is

```
class_<B>& def_readwrite_impl(char const* name, A B::*a,
  char const* doc, mpl::true_)
```

because `B::*a` should be a member of B but not a function pointer. That in turn invokes

```
class_<B>& def_readwrite_impl(char const* name, A B::*pm_, char const* doc, mpl::true_)
```

`pm_` is an unbound pointer to some object of type B's a member. 
Now, let's move on to `add_property`.

```
class_<B>& add_property(char const* name, A &fget = B::*a,
  A &fset = B::*a, char const* docstr = 0)
```

From here we go to boost/python/objects/class.hpp and look at `class_base::add_property`:

```
void add_property(char const* name, 
    object const& fget, object const& fset, char const* docstr);
```

Implementation is unfortunately hidden. But the signature shows that the magic happens in `make_getter`.

```
template <class F>
object make_getter(F f)
{
    typedef typename api::is_object_operators<F>::type is_obj_or_proxy;

    return this->make_fn_impl(
        detail::unwrap_wrapper((W*)0)
      , f, is_obj_or_proxy(), (char*)0, detail::is_data_member_pointer<F>()
    );
}
```

`unwrap_wrapper` is not doing anything to the pointer, because `std::shared_ptr` doesn't derive from `boost::python::wrapper`. 
`is_data_member_pointer` was already part of the first macro. I'm not sure if this is the broken part in your case because at some point digging for more decorators became really tedious.

Looking for some decorator definitions I stumbled upon bad news. Added it as a comment to your original question.

Comment: It's expected with strings as strings can be considered as POD types. 
The question is about whether boost.python has some mechanism to store once created wrappers rather than creating copies each time.

Comment: @AlexandraB. That depends on whether `a` is really seen as data. If it's seen as an access function, it will get called as such. I'll look into the [definition of `def_readwrite`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/boost/python/class.hpp) more deeply later in the day. So far, I've only found further generators rather than something actually stored.

Comment: what do you mean by 'doing anything to the pointer'? I suppose these signatures do not 'explain' how return value of a getter is managed. And this is the question: is there any caching(returned object lifetime tracking) involved when getting a member variable(its wrapper)?

Comment: "Doing anything to the pointer": wrapper types are being unwrapped, exposing the raw pointer. Which won't work with `std::smart_ptr`, because Boost only recognizes `boost::smart_ptr` as a wrapper (criterion is inheritance from `boost::python::wrapper`). This seems to be an error in Boost.  [The ticket on Boost GitHub seems to be in beta phase, reopened three times.](https://github.com/boostorg/python/issues/29) Was the bug fixed for your Boost version?