# boost.python return_internal_reference policy

Tags: c++, boost-python

For the following two classes:

```
class A {
};

class B {
public:

    B()
    : a_(std::make_shared<A>())
    {} 

    std::shared_ptr<A> a_;
};
```

there is a following simple `boost.python` wrapping

```
A& get_a(const B& b) {
    return *b.a_; // intentionally, no check here; doesn't matter for the example
}

boost::python::class_<A, std::shared_ptr<A>>("A");

boost::python::class_<B>("B")
   .def("get_a", &get_a, boost::python::return_internal_reference<>());
```

In Python there is simple members' retrieval:

```
import ext
b = ext.B()
a1 = b.get_a()
a2 = b.get_a()
```

What I expect is

```
id(a1) == id(a2)
```

which doesn't hold for the above case which means that two different `PyObject` as `A` wrappers are created. 
Why? Doesn't `return_internal_reference` policy prevents from creating multiple temporary objects?

If I return `std::shared_ptr<A>` from `get_a`, the programme fails to compile.

This question has similarities to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38826816/1202544). However, in the latter one there are temporary objects which are likely not to be kept track of. Here, on the other hand, member variables' wrappers are stored in python variables.

Answer (score 4):

The [`return_internal_reference`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/function_invocation_and_creation/models_of_callpolicies.html#function_invocation_and_creation.models_of_callpolicies.boost_python_return_internal_ref) policy allows returning pointers or references to internally held objects without having Boost.Python make a copy of the *referent*.  It does not imply that subsequent calls will return identical Python objects.

---

Here is an example [demonstrating](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/122071afeacb50d7) that the C++ object are not being copied when using `return_internal_reference`, and that multiple discrete Python objects may embed a reference to the same C++ object:

```cpp
#include <boost/python.hpp>
#include <cstdint> // std::uintptr_t

struct spam
{
  uintptr_t id() { return reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(this); }
};

struct egg {};

spam& get_spam(const egg&)
{
  static spam instance;
  return instance;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(example)
{
  namespace python = boost::python;

  python::class_<spam>("Spam")
    .def("id", &spam::id)
    ;

  python::class_<egg>("Egg")
    .def("get_spam", get_spam, python::return_internal_reference<>())
    ;
}
```

Interactive usage:

```python
import example
egg = example.Egg()
spam1 = egg.get_spam()
spam2 = egg.get_spam()
assert(spam1.id() == spam2.id()) # reference same C++ object
assert(id(spam1) != id(spam2))   # non-identical Python objects
```

Comment: Thank you. I had known that C++ objects had not been  copied but had had incorrect understanding of the policy.